# How to reword my question / Where to move my question to

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Is there a library for recording video in Python 3, with capabilities similar to Nvidia Shadowplay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267005/is-there-a-library-for-recording-video-in-python-3-with-capabilities-similar-to)*

How would you guys recommend I reword my question for it to be appropriate for Stack Overflow? If it's not feasible to reword my question, is there perhaps a better place to put the question?

Please note that in my question I'm not interested in how to implement the library that I'm thinking of creating, I simply would like input from others on whether or not a library with this functionality already exists publicly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah... You're not gonna be able to reword that to fit Stack Overflow. As the close reason states, we don't do "software" requests. It unfortunately leads to a poll of opinions, a popularity vote, and spam.

You *might* be able to make it fit in Software Recommendations, ***HOWEVER*** I do not know what their rules are, they are, from what I've heard, *very* strict on what they allow. **Be sure to check their [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/asking) before you post your question there.**

If you can't make it fit there, there unfortunately isn't another spot it would be suitable on the network. Good luck, and thanks for taking the time to try to improve your post and the network.